# Alternative IDE for compiling and running arduino code?

Tags: c++, ide

I am not super experienced with c++ and I know that the syntax for C++ and the code written/compiled by the arduino IDE are slightly different.

---

I would like to be able to write code, compile it the same way the arduino IDE does, and run it, without uploading it to a board.

---

I dont need to test any code that interacts with any hardware. I simply want to be able to test basic syntax to make sure my concepts work before integrating with the full program.

I have written a few Arduino programs and I think the most complicated thing I've used were pointer functions, but I'd like to be able to test out code without needing to upload to a board for every change, while relying on Serial.print.

I have found alternatives that help with debugging and although that is helpful, I'd like to avoid the need to upload to a board every time I want to test changes for basic concepts

Comment: google `arduino emulator`

Comment: Thats a reasonable option, but i still would need to upload to a board, just an emulated one, I could just use a throwaway board I have and skip the hassle of dealing with the emulator. I appreciate the suggestion though

Comment: it is now unclear what you are asking ... you want to compile and run  Arduino code without any hardware, real or virtual ... what would the program do? ... it would have no way to interact with you

Comment: Use proteus with arduino library.

Comment: similar to using repl.it - I would like to be able to write code, that gets compiled and ran similar to what the arduino ide does. I am trying to test out different syntax for concepts I dont understand. I dont need to test working with hardware.

Comment: sorry if this is a stupid question. I was just hoping to reduce some steps in the process so I could learn the language quicker. I am a web developer but for some reason c++ is harder for me than id like to admit

Comment: "... syntax for C++ and the code written/compiled by the arduino IDE are slightly different." The Arduino IDE accepts standard C++. What it does differently, to assist learners, is to notice when you've referred to a library (that it know about!) and provides it even if you forgot to '#include" it, and forward declarations for functions, if you forgot those. If you write correct C++, it will compile in any standard C++ environment, including the Arduino IDE.

Comment: The difference of C++ and higher level (script) languages is that C++ is really near to the hardware. So running compilations on a PC, can be different from running it on a raspi or an Arduino.  And there are differences even then you don't use Hardware function directly. e.g an int on a Arduino can have another size then on a PC. And beside that, what is the purpose of learning Arduino C++ without Hardware functions? This language is designed for a MCU, that's pure hardware. You can learn how pointers work (and so on), by using plain C++.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the difference, I suppose I can just use repl.it or even visual studio. I appreciate everyone's input!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any C++ IDE you like, best when bundled with a compiler, for example Code::Blocks. Assuming you're using Windows: A combination of a decent editor like Notepad++ and some good compiler chain like MinGW will do, too. If you absolutely have to you could also use MS Visual Studio, I don't bother.

Then create standard console programs with this `main()`:

```
void setup();
void loop();

int main()
{
    setup();
    for (;;)
    {
        loop();
    }
}
```

And append your hardware-less Arduino code.

Comment: Need to get rid of Serial.print at least :) :-) 
But alas, with a debugger, you don't need that Serial.print at all.

Comment: One could write a simple `Serial` class with a minimal interface that prints to `stdout` or the native debugger channel.

Answer (score 2):

[PlatformIO](https://platformio.org/platformio-ide) is a plugin for Visual Studio Code that has support for many embedded device, including most Arduinos

Comment: The principle question seems to be about testing their code, in some capacity, without having to upload to an Arduino on each test.  It would probably help to say how PlatformIO enables this.